# .BIN file for ROM IC using proteus

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, proteus, rom

Trying to load a .bin file into a 2732 ROM chip in Proteus.

Having trouble finding the exact layout of code I need for the .BIN file.

So far i have tried writing the following in notepad and saving it as .bin

00000001
00000000
00000001
00000001

and outputting the data at the first 4 address spaces but i doesnt seem to have 'loaded' in the data I entered.

Maybe iam missing something like a header or some other key words in my .BIN file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A ".bin" file would clearly be a *binary* one, while you seem to be creating a *text* file containing something else, perhaps a printable hex dump.

Depending on what your source material is, you may be able to have the a tool specific to that flow translate to a binary output, for example with a gcc-style toolchain you can use `objcopy` for this.

Or you can find various "hex editor" tools which will let you *edit* in a format not unlike what you depict, but then *save* to a raw binary format.

If there is some organization to the file beyond flat binary, that would be something imposed by whatever is going to read your EPROM, not by the chip itself.  So it is not something which could be determined from information in your question.  Most commonly however, for systems which use *single* byte-wide storage devices there is not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. Iam assuming then I use the hex editor tool you mentioned to create the raw binary format I require?

Comment: If you want to enter or modify the contents by hand, then yes, that would be a reasonable way to do it.  If the contents are coming from something else, I'd personally rather have that do it, or write an output routine to do so.